# Posting with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

So i have a form like so:

```
 <form>
     <input type="submit" value="X" id="deleteButton" onclick="ConfirmChoice(<?php echo $id; ?>)" />
 </form>
```

and a function like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function ConfirmChoice(theid) 
{ 
    var dataString = 'id=' + theid;
    answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this song?");
    if (answer !=0) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "deleteSong.php",
            data: dataString,
        });
    } 
}

</script>
```

So basically I want it to delete whatever they click on from my database which deleteSong will take care of. 
It gives the id of the song and as far as I know should confirm deletion then delete it right?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: add a return false; statement in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it from

`input type="submit"` to

```
input type="button"
```

Comment: So  changing this has worked. Thanks. As it is sent with ajax how can I get the page to refresh after it's all done to update changefs?

Comment: location.reload(); does refresh the page , but the whole point of doing ajax that you don't want to refresh the page i guesss ! and yeah well if the answer solved your issue you should mark it as correct answer ! (this will help who ever reading this question in future , this will help the one who gave the answer, it will help you since you are marking correct answers more people will be willing to answer your questions )

Answer (score 0):

Also because your are not setting it, the request to the server is in json which in your case is badly formed.

Try something like this:

```
 var dataString = "{'id'= '"+ theid + "'}";
```

this should make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without knowing where exactly the problem is. Is deleteSong.php working correctly?

Like others have said you should change the input type to `button` or return false from your function, otherwise the browser will try and submit the form in the normal manner but as you haven't specified an `action` within the `<form>` tag it won't work properly.

Personally, I would do things quite differently:

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="button" value="<?php echo $id ?>" id="deleteButton">
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#deleteButton').click(function () {
         var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this song?");
         if (!answer) {
             return false;
         }
         var data = 'id=' + $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'deleteSong.php',
             data: dataString,
             success: function (response) {
                 // response will contain the output from your php script.
                 // Do something with it here. If you just want to see what it
                 // says, do something like:
                 console.log(response);
                 // then look in the console (view > javascript console in chrome)
             }
         });
     });
});
```

Just to explain what I'm doing here (sorry if I'm telling you things you already know, I want to be as explicit as possible for anyone who might be reading this in the future:)

- I enclose the whole thing in `$(document).ready(function() { ... } );` so it only gets run when the page is finished loading, other wise you might end up trying to bind functions to the click action on a button that doesn't exist yet.
- `if (answer !=0)` is redundant, you can just write `if (!answer)` as any positive integer will evaluate to `true`
- I included a `success` callback above which might help you in debugging.

Is there only going to be one 'delete' button on the entire page? Or is there going to be a delete button next to every song? If it's the latter, you'll have to give each button a different ID, not just `deleteButton` because all IDs must be unique.

If the above doesn't work, are you sure that jQuery has loaded correctly? To check, type `jQuery` in the console, if you don't get an error then you're fine. The other possibility is that something's wrong with your `deleteSong.php` script but I can't help you there without seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Feel free to explain everything as much as you want as i'm relatively new to all this. Yes it does have an delete next to every song. So I decided to just pass the id into the function. As it works now I'm pretty happy with it but I want to know more about the document.ready function. When I include that it doesn't work so I am considering leaving it out but, I feel like it is very necessary to avoid the problem you described. Should I pursue making my code work with that?

Comment: How would I make the ID unique but still manage to get the all in the function if i's dynamic?

Comment: It looks like you don't really need to use an ID, instead you could store the ID of the song in `value` like I've done above then get it using `.val()` in jQuery. You could then give all the buttons a CLASS `deleteButton` and bind the function to them with `$('.deleteButton').click(function () { ..... })`.

Comment: Not sure why `$(document).ready()` isn't working - are you enclosing it another function that might be interfering with it? Also NB that `document` shouldn't have `'`s around it, i.e. don't write `$('document').ready()`. (Also, a caveat to my other comment is that if you have a large number of delete buttons it might be more sensible to bind the click function to an ancestor element with `on`, e.g. `$(body).on('click', '.deleteButton', function () { ... } )`, although what I wrote above will still work.